# Connecting to mysql database from ios

Tags: mysql, ios, database

What is the right way to connect to database from an iphone app? I built a website and now I want to biild an app that can enter and veiw information from the database, like autotrader and rightmove how they get the same information on the website in the iphone app?

Comment: Have you tried the Apple developer forums? Or anything at all? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com Also, this has less than nothing to do with PHP, so I'm retagging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a REST API (PHP) fetch & update data from  the centralized Mysql DB. 
You can call this through NSURLConnection. Your REST API returns XML or JSON.from you coding u can write coding to parse.